# Every null sequence is a bounded sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Every null sequence is a bounded sequnce.** For choose $\epsilon = 1$ then we have $|z_v|<1$ for $v>\mu$ and hence $|z_v| \le k = \max(1, |z_0|,
>  \ldots, |z_{\mu}|)$.

Could someone please explain this proof, specifically where the constant $k$ comes from.

Comment: To be a null sequence, it must tend to 0, therefore it is convergent. Every convergent sequence is bounded. $k$ is the maximum value of elements in the sequence up to index $\mu$

Comment: I think that's a different definition of null sequence to the one I'm using - which is the epsilon delta version. I'm not sure how to prove that these definitions are equivalent either. I know that k is the maximum of indexed elements of the sequence, but I'm not sure where it came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument stated in your question is unclear; let me re-present the idea:

Let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence; let $x_{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Then by definition there is some $N \geq 1$ such that 
$|x_{n} - 0| = |x_{n}| < 1$ for all $n \geq N$. We have bounded the "tail" sequence $(x_{n})_{n \geq N}$ from above by $1$; it remains to bound the set $\{ x_{1}, \dots, x_{N-1} \}$. But this is easy; the number $M := \max_{1 \leq k \leq N-1}|x_{k}|$ is a natural upper bound. Hence we conclude that
$$
|x_{n}| \leq \max \{ M, 1 \}
$$
for all $n \geq 1$.

In fact, as you may have noted, the same idea generalizes easily to every convergent sequence by applying suitably a version of the triangle inequality.

Comment: Brilliant! I appreciate this, many thanks.